# NServiceBus: accessing RabbitMQ IBasicProperties when sending message

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I'm using RabbitMQ with NServiceBus. I send message to some queue where a third party service reads it.

It turned out that service requires `encoding_type` property set to utf-8 which I cannot set through NServiceBus (or can I?).

I wonder if there is a possibillity to access `IBasicProperties` of RabbitMQ client when I sending message.

Getting a property object in Behavior handlers unfortunately doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the headers of a message, you can:
https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/headers

Comment: Unfortunatelly setting message header doesn't solve the problem. Encoding_type should be set directly in message properties.

Comment: What I understand from the code on RabbitMQ website itself, is that we add headers to the message properties like anyone should. So I would not know how to do it any other way?
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html